# Safeway to cast Windows CreateFile handle to 'long' and vice versa in C++

Tags: c++

Is it safe or correct way to cast windows CreateFile return type ("HANDLE") to long datatype and vice versa ie long value to HANDLE type?
If the approach is correct then how it can be done in Windows 7 Environment?
32 bit handling will be fine but any portable code to handle 64 bit version it can be a best shot.

Comment: No, there isn't a way to correctly cast a HANDLE to a long and back.

Comment: `HANDLE` is probably implemented as an opaque pointer, so casting it to/from `uintptr_t` **shouldn't** give you problems. But it is not really safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HANDLE` is probably implemented as an opaque pointer, so casting it to/from `uintptr_t` **shouldn't** give you problems. **But it is not really safe.** No conversion from implementation-defined datatype to integer is safe, and no conversion from pointer to integer is safe.

Pointers should remain pointers.

Implementation-defined types should not be converted.

Integer should stay integers.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply.. Could you throw me some light what would be the side effects of casting? and how it makes application prone to error. Sorry I lack knowledge in this topic

Comment: If you cast a pointer to an integer, then you lose any knowledge about it being a pointer. If you modify it as an integer, and then cast it back, anything bad can happen. Also, you loose information about which kind of pointer it was, and then, if you cast it to the wrong pointer type, you not only risk having wrong results, but you also break strict-aliasing, invalidating some tricks the compiler may have used.

Comment: @Lo1234 the same applies for implementation-defined types.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to correctly cast a `HANDLE` to a `long` and back.

Consider that on 64-bit Windows, `long` is 32 bits long and `HANDLE` is 64 bits long.

Comment: I actually need to pass this handle to 32 bit application... where it has long datatype as 32 bit..

Comment: @Lo1234 What is the point of passing a handle to another application?

Comment: Actually I am creating a dll and providing API's to 3rd party app...OpenFile and Close File is done by that application so I thought passing handle it would be easier.

Comment: @Lo1234 Well you can't use a 32-bit DLL in a 64-bit application or vice versa, so it should be easy to just pass the HANDLE around.